# Find bases of a trapezoid with given midline and legs

Tags: geometry

Given trapezoid ABCD with $\angle AOB = 60°$, $AD = 3$ cm, $BC = 8$ cm, $MN (midline) = 8.5$ cm.

Find $AB$, $DC$ (the bases) and the area of the trapezoid $S$.

[image]

There are two formulas that I could use to find the area of the trapezoid. Since we already have the midline, I will probably have to use the second formula below, which means I need to find the height.

$S = \frac{(AB + CD) \times h}{2}$ or $S = MN \times h$ => $MN = \frac{AB + DC}{2}$

I wish I could add more to the question related to what I've tried, but I really have no idea where to start from.

Comment: They should probably be named M and N, but that’s by definition

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, my drawing was horrible. It's better rn.

Comment: Can you use trig?

Comment: @Vasya everything should be possible as soon as it solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment: the given value for angle AOB is wrong . the correct value is $135^o$, only with this value the figure can be constructed. In this case:

$AB=123.69$

$DC=46.31$

$altitude=29.83$

To moderator: I can not comment and I can not attach figure. I do not know what is wrong ? Is it due to site? Please guide.The top titles are vanished.And every time I want to post my answer the site ask me for human verification.